# Transparent data caching in multi-site environment

Tags: nfs, cache

I need an advice on choice of the right technology for my problem. I have geographically distributed multi-site environment where there is one main site and a number of remote sites.

- Main site generates terrabytes of data on dayly basis (~30% of data is fully re-generated every day)
- This is impractical to replicate all data to remote sites
- Data is currently shared via NFS and remote sites have pretty slow access to the share
- Users on remote site usually very use small subset of data on the share (few gigabytes)
- Users on remote site tend to use the same data during the day
- Access is strictly read-only

So it looks pretty reasonable to have something like caching NFS proxy on each site so that

- Only the first access to the file on the share is slow
- Subsequent accesses are much faster because cache hit ratio is expected to be very high

I was able to configure similar caching on linux machine using FSCache, cachefilesd and mounting NFS share with "-o fsc" and got very good results. However, when I tried to configure NFS server which would mount share with local caching enabled and then re-export it, I've hit some issues. Quick google search shown that NFS is not designed for such use-cases.

I wonder if there is a better technology for this particular problem. I'm interested in some open-source software-only solution (ideally working on top of NFS because it's hard to get rid of the main NFS share in this setup). Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe the actual business workflow a little more? What are the files?

Comment: Is data static or does your site use data to process it and produce some results based on that data input. If your data is static e.g. media files consider using CDN.